# WIN7+ PHP7 + POSTGRES 9.5 + APACHE 2.4 MISSING PDO

Tags: php, apache, postgresql, pdo

my phpinfo () can not load the 'php_pdo_pgsql.dll' and 'php_pgsql.dll'. The dlls are inside the folder 'c: / php / ext' correctly!

[image]

---

Now, if I uncomment the pdo MYSQL and restarting APACHE, it is usually loaded! the problem happens only with POSTGRES!
[image]

Any solution? Thank you!

Comment: I am amazed why some people give negative vote, and does not explain the reason for the negative vote! f**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a Windows server, configured with Apache, i added the following line to httpd.conf to load libpq.dll solved the my problem:

LoadFile "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/libpq.dll"

Comment: I knew that!! so it's an X Y Problem ! you have asked about PDO the time you are not even loading POSTGRES correctly !!